# Checking presence of users in a database

Tags: oracle11g

Am running a select query to check the availability of a user in a particular database

```
SELECT * FROM dba_users WHERE username='<username>'
```

Now the concern is that i have multiple databases to be checked where this query has to be executed.

Is there a way to modify the query in such a way that it can be executed on all the databases at the same time ie, check the user's availability in all databases by using a **single** query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A database link might help.

Choose one of the database you'd want to run that query on, and create database links to all other databases. Then run a query on `UNION` of all those `DBA_USERS` (I used `ALL_USERS` as I have access to it).

For example:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger@db11
Connected.
SQL> create database link dbl_db20
  2  connect to user_name_here
  3  identified by its_password_here
  4  using 'xx.yy.zz.ww:1521/db20';

Database link created.

SQL> select *
  2  from (select 'DB11' what, username from all_users@db11
  3        union all
  4        select 'DB20' what, username from all_users@dbl_db20
  5       )
  6  where username = 'SCOTT';

WHAT USERNAME
---- ------------------------------
DB11 SCOTT

SQL>
```